# Setting Gmail as mail server

Tags: dns, email, gmail

I’m in a slightly weird situation right now, and I don’t have sufficient knowledge to sort this myself without truly understand what I’m doing.

Yesterday, I’ve registered a domain (.com) and ordered a VPS, attached to that domain. Chances are I may receive mail on my .com address to confirm the domain. Unfortunately, that domain is nothing, but an empty domain.

Currently, there’s no mailserver that fetches my mail. Because I don’t have a mailserver available, I (temporarily) want to use Gmail. I prefer to add it to my existing, personal address, but I’m okay with creating a new account as well. I just want to read possible incoming mails.

I’ve tried to set MX records to

**What do I need to do to get mail to a Gmail address?**

PS. I’m aware of Google, NSA, etc.

PPS. I just want to receive mail. I don’t care if I can’t send via my domain.

PPS. Detailed steps would be greatly appreciated, I’m a noob.

Comment: How long will it take to get the VPS up and running? You can just install mail software on your VPS can't you?

Comment: @Dave It is a very very bad idea to setup a mail server of your own unless you are a specialist at doing that. Mail servers get blacklisted all of the time and when they do your server\IP become almost useless on the Internet. All it takes is one zero day to come along and your done. Once you are blacklisted it is almost impossible to get removed from the blacklist.

Comment: Hmmmm.... I see the concern @krowe, but when I first did it, 10+ years ago (oh dear my age!) , I was not an expert (nor am I still); I just did some research and that was it really! Never had an issue (although there isn't a huge amount of traffic on my servers).

Comment: What ISP is providing you with the VPS? Who is the domain's registrar?

Comment: Gmail will not accept mail for yourrandomsite.com, because it's not its responsibility. You can configure it so if you pay money. If that's not what you want, you'll have to look for another service which offers email hosting for your custom domain for free or cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is setup a `Gmail for Business` account. This will give you the ability to create and manage Gmail accounts which look like regular domain email addresses (eg yourname@yoursite.com). This cost $50/yr and is completely professional looking. Here is the link to get you started: https://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/products/gmail/index.html

I would explain it more but they do a really good job of it on the site so there is no need.

**Update**

I had forgotten but it is now a pay service.

Comment: Thanks. I’ve come across Google Apps in my search, but I just want to temporarily receive my mail. That’s it.

Comment: @TimS. If you want a 'GMail' email account which uses your domain this is the only option. Use it for however long you like though, when you're done remove the record you added to your DNS and it'll be gone. If you just want to forward email from some other account to your GMail account I'm not sure what the problem is but I cannot help you beyond saying that the option to do that is going to be in your current email account settings.

Comment: FYI: Google Apps accounts are no longer free. With a 12-month commitment, price today is $50 per year per account. (But multiple email aliases can be added for free within the context of a single account.)

Answer (score 1):

I was in similar situation earlier. And the only solution i found is to use postfix and set it up properly in your vps.

Here is a simple guide for you: http://ostechnix.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/setup-mail-server-using-postfixdovecotsquirrelmail-in-centosrhelscientific-linux-6-3-step-by-step/

And then use this guide to setup auto forwarder to your gmail account : https://www.bentasker.co.uk/documentation/linux/173-configuring-postfix-to-automatically-forward-mail-for-one-address-to-another

If these are set up, u dont have to do anything else.. All mails will be coming to your Gmail inbox.